# Xamarin Droid Google Maps Not Showing Up

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I've started having this problem after the Google Play Services update from the App store last week.

Basically: in my dev project i was using (not sure why) a Browser key created on the google developer console and everything was working fine.

I then changed the google key with an ANDROID key, updated the debugkey (by deleting it and got automatically a new one), re-calculated the SHA1 for the debugkey, updated the key in the manifest, but now the map it's not displayed in my activity/fragment.

I tried several times recreating the key, resigning the package, even changing the debugkey.
It does not get displayed both in the debug and release version, as well as when i create the apk for the store thru visual studio, signing it with the storekey.

I also tried several times to recreate a browser key on google console and using that in my manifest. No luck.

PS: permissions are set in both manifest as well as a requestpermission Location for marshmallow CoarseLocation and FineLocation from the code behind following the android 6.0 pattern for requesting permissions.

The map is displayed with a grey grid, in the output console i get com.google.android.gms signature not valid

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="<here_i_have_my_key>" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at the output window, usually it will show some sort of warning if key is incorrect for example..

Comment: where are you testing? in an emulator or real device?

Comment: I am testing on real device.

I don't get any warning of incorrect key, since the key is registered correctly on google developer console with sha and packagename.

I get this in the output window
`com.packagename signature not valid.  Found: 
05-27 18:10:47.704 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(27509):`

and a superlong string afterwards

Comment: In the logcat i see
`googleservice failed to initialize, status 10, missing an expected resource R.string.google_app_id` for initializing google services

Comment: 05-27 22:22:52.414 I/Google Maps Android API(16265): Google Play services client version: 8487000
05-27 22:22:52.424 I/Google Maps Android API(16265): Google Play services package version: 9083438

Does this help anyhow? This mismatch between packages ?

Comment: Update: I tried the sample api coming with the xamarin component, and it works well (same apikey, same debug.keystore, same devices, same pc, same permissions), but it uses framelayout, while in my project i'm using the mapview.

Comment: HI All..

I figured the problem was that i was using the mapview.

I changed my axml layout to use the fragment and now everything works fine.

PS: gotta be aware that using a fragment inside a fragment requires using ChildFragmentManager or it throws exceptions.

Cheers